# How to create a no-op Hibernate Criteria restriction

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

What is the idiomatic way to add a no-op `Criterion` restriction? Ie, what is the null object pattern for the criterion API?

Comment: Well, don't add any restriction. And instead of adding noise to your question, you should elaborate: what's the problem you're trying to solve? What have you tried? Getting good answers goes faster when you ask a good question.

Comment: @JBNizet My question is clear and concise. Your answer is non-constructive. A no-op has [a clear definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP), and "don't add any restriction" does not fit it. If you don't know the answer, don't bother commenting. If you want me to ask a different question that you might know the answer to, don't bother commenting.

Comment: I probably know the answer, but I don't know what the problem is... because your question is awful. What do you gain in asking such a bad question, instead of doing what I suggest: elaborating on what problem you're trying to solve? You have 1 line for your unclear question, then 10 lines of noise, then 4 lines of justification of the clearness of your question. Insted of wasting your time adding noise, do YOURSELF a favor, and elaborate.

Comment: Why do you insist on asking why I am looking for this information?  Nobody likes that. Isn't SO Q&A about staying general? If you must know, it's so that I could write one-liners that include, eg, `.add( time!=null ? Restrictions.ge( "time", time.getTime() ) : ...no-op... )`. But maybe someone else wants to return a no-op criterion from a function. My only fault, perhaps, is not phrasing it as "create a no-op `Criterion`". In what other way, besides not giving the story of my childhood, is my question "awful"?

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly. No one likes answers of the type, "I never do it that way, therefore what you're doing is nonsense." But thank you for suggesting `Restrictions.conjunction()`. Looking at the source, `Restrictions.and()` and `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1")` are also equivalent. Next time I'll try describing my "problem" (I'm sure that will be *very* easy), and next time you should try just answering the question (without worrying whether the OP should have asked it--in contrast to the IRC chat you linked, this won't turn into a conversation. It'll stay a Q&A that anyone can find and use.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing "idiomatic," but you can use:

- `Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1")`
- `Restrictions.and()`
- `Restrictions.or()`
- `Restrictions.conjunction()`

Or:

```
final static Criterion NOOP_CRITERION = new Criterion() 
{
       @Override public String 
    toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
            return "1=1";
        }
       @Override public TypedValue[] 
    getTypedValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
            return new TypedValue[0];
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aleksandr for persevering with your question. I also wanted  NOOP for the same purpose - to have one concise line of code instead of extra objects, extra conditionals, etc. HIbernate allows this .add() chaining for more efficient coding, so they should define a NOOP as well to facilitate the ? : operator.